# Rotate frame but not image

Tags: css, web, transform

I want to rotate a frame but not the image inside it. Here is a JSFiddle that does the rotation but the image still moves. How can I keep the image stationary but move the frame only.

https://jsfiddle.net/q6n2w4qm/2/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="center">
<div class="hexagon">
<div class="hexagon-in1">
<div class="hexagon-in2">

</div></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.center{
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.hexagon{
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.hexagon-in1{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hexagon-in2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);  
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/250/350/city');
  repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;

}  

.hexagon:hover{   
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: rotate(150deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) PNG pseudo-mask overlay

I created a simple HTML/CSS solution, but is only possible with the following three criteria:

1. The background color behind the image is a solid color
2. There is enough margin on all sides of the image
3. You have Photoshop or some comparable image editing software

**Working Example**

```css
body {
  background-color:#222222;
}

.hex-hack {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.base-image {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  margin: 84px;
}

.hex-overlay {
  position:absolute;
  width:568px;
  height:568px;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:3;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.hex-overlay:hover {
   -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="hex-hack">
    <img class="base-image" src="https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-g-400-400-2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="hex-overlay" src="https://i.imgur.com/zYa31Tw.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Note that the margin of the top image is half of the difference between the widths of the bottom image and the top image to keep it centered.

**How I Made the Hexagon Mask in Photoshop**

I started with a 400 by 400 image on a 800 by 800 canvas and created a perfect circle around the image so that each corner pixel of the image touched the circle. I cropped the canvas down to the width of the circle (568px). The purpose of this is to guarantee that the image is completely covered as the hexagon mask rotates.

Next, I had to create a 350 by 400 hexagon with no fill, rotate it 30 degrees, and center it in the middle of the canvas. Then I selected the hexagon's pixels (ctrl + click the hexagon layer), inverted the selection (shift + ctrl + I), and filled a new layer with the #222222 background color. I hid every other layer and saved it as a png.

### 2) CSS clip-path and animate

Another possible solution for you to consider is to use CSS to animate an image's clipping path via the clip-path and animate properties. This might be an easier approach, however, the clip-path property is relatively new and doesn't have the greatest browser support - especially with IE, Edge, and Opera. Here are a couple resources to check out:

[CSS Masking](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) - Excellent article on the clip-path property (includes animation demo)

[Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) - Great tool for creating CSS clip-paths

### 3) SVG animation and clipPath

Finally, this is a very browser-friendly solution, but you'll need some software (like Illustrator) to create an SVG from an image. This is also something I have no actual experience with, but I'm positive it can be achieved with a little research, and some trial and error. Here are some resources to get you started.

[SVG clipping/masking techniques](https://getflywheel.com/layout/css-svg-clipping-and-masking-techniques/)

[Animating SVGs with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any solution that will work on even the slightly older browsers?

Comment: @EddieS I've updated my answer to give you two other options.